# Exporting/Importing components in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie in React.js. I am making one small app, which have authentification and some components. 
I divided applications to some components. First is App.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Login = require('./Login.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        url: 'url-to-my-API'
    };

},
render: function() {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
            return (
                <Login url={this.state.url} />
                )

    } else {
        alert('Browser is not supported. Browser must support localStorage.')
        return (
        <div />
        )
    }   
}});

module.exports = App;
```

Login.jsx component consist form for authorize user and submit button which loads new component for user. This component consists of menu and logout button. When user click to logout button, there is onClick event to Logout.jsx component.
Logout.jsx looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Login = require('./Login.jsx');

var Logout = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        url: this.props.url,
        login: false
    }
},
logout: function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('username', '');
    localStorage.setItem('token', '');  
    this.backToLoginPage();
    document.getElementById('appContent').innerHTML = '';
},
backToLoginPage: function() {
    this.setState({
        login: true
    });
},
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    if (this.state.login) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Login url={localStorage.getItem('url')} />, document.getElementById('appLogin'));
    }
},
render: function() {
    if (this.state.login) {
        return (
            <span />
            )
    } else {

    return (
        <button name="logout" className="logoutButton btn primary" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
        )
}
}});

module.exports = Logout;
```

If user click to logout button it returns this:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Can you help me with this what am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: are you using webpack and babel?

Comment: Štefan Ondáš [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115687/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed syntax of my components from this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Login = require('./Login.jsx');

var Logout = React.createClass({ ...
```

to this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RectDOM from 'react-dom';
import Login from './Login';

export default class Logout extends React.Component { ...
```

it's working now.

Because it's ES6, I had to change functions of initial state (to constructor()) and bind every every action event.

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Donot try to render in componentdidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    if (this.state.login) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Login url={localStorage.getItem('url')} />, document.getElementById('appLogin'));
    }
},
```

This is incorrect

Correct way is to handle it in the render function

```
render: function() {
    if (this.state.login) {
        return (
            <Login url={localStorage.getItem('url')} />
            )
    } else {

    return (
        <button name="logout" className="logoutButton btn primary" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
        )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I made with componentDidUpdate because I wanted to add content to specific div (by ID), like this (ReactDOM.render ...). Can you write how to add content to my div in your example? Must Login.jsx have this line of code -- ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document...); ?

Comment: And btw, I tried this and it don't to remove my problem -- Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: you should inform the App component using context or passing prop function  that it needs to display now Login box basically change the state of the App component to login false

Regarding the error make sure you are returning a react class. Can u see the console where this came from ?

Comment: It came from react generated code. Maybe this helps.. if I have all components in one file, everything is OK. It is something like bad reference  (bad import/export class) to class, but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: make sur u are doing module.exports  not module.export 
some compoennt might be returning as object check your login.jsx

Comment: yes I am doing module.exports, I think that login.jsx is OK, because like I wrote, when I put all components into one file without exporting, everything is ok.

Comment: in your app.jsx why are u exporting module.exports = Login 
see the topmost code u have posted

Comment: Yes, I did mistake here but in my code is module.exports = App;

Comment: can you remove this statement       alert('Browser is not supported. Browser must support localStorage.') Can u share your code on fiddle everything looks fines here,
although i have corrected this error numerous times , but need to reproduce it myself

Comment: I can't share my project, but I can share this: https://gitlab.websupport.sk/stefan.ondas/exportProblem/tree/master It consist of 4 components and  webpack config file. Here miss only component which is for connect to API.

Comment: Plz add getIniitalState to all the components 
this line would surely break in header this.state.username = localStorage.getItem('username');

Comment: Yes, I have getInitialState in all components (in git it is only example of app). In Header I have getInitialState with username, userApiToken etc. These states I use for connect to API. As I wrote, my problem is that when I click on button LOGOUT (it could reset content and show login form) I got warning and Uncaught Invariant Violation.

Comment: Aand everything is OK if I have all components in one file. But there are a lot of lines of code for one file (bad for reading...), so I want to divide this (every component will be one separate file). Maybe in webpack config I must to do something different..

Comment: What we can do is in the chrom dev console check break onexception true (right hand side below top button).
Now there on whenever this incorrect violation is occuring we will trace the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

In App js Check module.exports, maybe it should be `module.exports = App , rather than Login`
And check path in `var Login = require('./Login.jsx');`

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Login = require('./Login.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        url: 'url-to-my-API'
    };

},
render: function() {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
            return (
                <Login url={this.state.url} />
                )

    } else {
        alert('Browser is not supported. Browser must support localStorage.')
        return (
        <div />
        )
    }   
}});

module.exports = App;
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this, but there was the same error.

Comment: are you using webpack and babel?

Comment: can you provide a gist?

Comment: I am using webpack

Comment: can you provide a gist or repo?

Comment: why you are using require insted of import

Comment: import and require have the same result, isn't it? I tried this.. Could you give me a link on some of your git repo where I can find how you to do this? Or could you give me an advice how to make it better?

Comment: Here is part of my code https://gitlab.websupport.sk/stefan.ondas/exportProblem/tree/master I can't share my project, but I can share this:  It consist of 4 components and  webpack config file. Here miss only component which is for connect to API.

Comment: Authorize component not found

Comment: Authorize is component with connection to API, I can't share it.

Comment: I don't understand.. Could you share with me tested files with your edit? If you click on Logout, there is no error in console?

Comment: i replace auth comp with this :  ``` ReactDOM.render(<div >
     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! {this.state.username} {this.state.password} {this.state.url}
  </div>
        , document.getElementById('appHeader'));```   for testing purpose

Comment: BTW! you didn't import that comp